# Using switch statement and reading data from SqlDataAdapter in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a `switch` statement by accessing data in the `DataTable` using `SqlDataAdapter` but not sure how to access the fields using switch statement.

Here is what I have started:

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT NAME, DEPARTMENT, LOCATION from MyTable WHERE ID =  @ID", con);

  DataTable dt= new DataTable();
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(ID));
  da.Fill(dt);

  DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
```

here is where I get lost and I am sure the switch statement below is not the right syntax

```
switch (dt[0].Location)
   {
       case 1:
       lblStage.Text = dt[0].Location.ToString() + " - It has been completed.";
        break;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(row["Location"].ToString());

switch (temp)
{
    case 1:
    lblStage.Text = temp.ToString() + " has been completed";
    break;

    case 2:
    lblStage.Text = temp.ToString() + " has been completed";
    break;

    default:
    // Perform altrenative, default logic
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks IrishChieftain, one thing to note is the Location field is an integer number like 1,2,3 and etc so i want to change the string temp into int temp.  How would i do that?  thanks

Comment: i want to say like: case 1: lblStage.Text = temp + " has been completed";
    break;

Comment: Put the for loop in a method and call it in each case statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `Convert.ToInt32(dt[0]["Location"].ToString())` in the switch statement